# High Silica content in well water is etching glass shower doors - Help!

Tags: doors, shower, glass, stain

We have two showers with the frameless glass shower doors that look horrible from the buildup, and these doors were "treated" when we bought them so we wouldn't have to worry about buildup. We are on well water and I had the water tested, calcium is very low - 30.6 ppm or about 1.75 grains, Manganese is a little high at 0.06ppm, and Silica (SiO2) is 29.63 ppm. Im reading that whole house reverse osmosis is about the only solution - but it's very, very expensive. Any other ideas?

Comment: Its probably soap buildup.  Please post a picture

Comment: How much to replace / repair all the devices in the house slowly being affected by the silica? How much for the RO filters? Now define expensive.

Comment: You have a point.